# Extracting argument from boost::function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-thread, c++98

I have a code like this

```
int foo(int x) {
    cout<<"Argument passed x = "<<x;
    return x;
}
int main() {
    boost::function<void ()> fn = boost::bind(foo, 10);
    // can I get 10 out of fn object
    // if (fn._1 == 10) {
    //    return;
    //}
    fn();
}
```

I want to implement a logic saying that if fn - 1st argument is 10 don't execute fn. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [boost `visit_each`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.implementation.visit_each_support) facility might be the ticket - but as it is  *experimental and undocumented* I don't have further information ...

Oh wait, I do know: it is in fact what you want as [their example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bind/bind_visitor.cpp), [compiled and executed on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/NiVDMw), shows.